# Vlookup XLRD Python

Tags: python, xlrd, vlookup

I have a xls spreadsheet that looks like below

```
Number  Code         Unit
1       Widget 1     20.0000 
2       Widget 2     4.6000 
3       Widget 3     2.6000 
4       Widget 4     1.4500
```

I have created the following code:

```
import xlrd
wb=xlrd.open_workbook('pytest.xls')
xlsname = 'pytest.xls'
book = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsname)

sd={}
for s in book.sheets():
    sd[s.name] = s
sheet=sd["Prod"]

Number = sh.col_values(0)
Code = sh.col_values(1)
Unit = sh.col_values(2)
```

Now this is where I am getting stuck, what i need to do is ask a question on what Number they choose, for this example lets say they choose 3, it needs to do print the answer for the unit. So if they choose 4 it prints 1.450. This document is 10k's long so manually entering the data into python is not viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you'd just need to do this:

```
 Unit[Number.index(value)]
```

Which will return the value from the Unit column that corresponds to the value specified for the Number column.

The `index()` function on a Python sequence returns the index of the first occurence of the provided value in the sequence. This value gets used to as the index to find the corresponding entry from `Unit`.

Comment: ig0774, thank you for this, it worked perfectly, I do have one more question that relates to this. If I do the look up on the code, inside the cell I impoted it reads widget1, when I do a print of the cell it reads u'widget1. If I type in widget 1 it says a error of not defined, if I type u'widget1 it errors before running as it believes it is a unfinished string. thanks